# vuejs - bootstrap-select options not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I have this select:

```
                <select v-model="filterState" @change="search()" class="selectpicker livesearch form-control" ref="stateSelect" id="stateSelect">
                    <option value="">Alle Status</option>
                    <option v-for="assignmentState in assignmentStates" v-bind:value="assignmentState.state">
                        {{ assignmentState.state }}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

It will only work when I refresh it like this:

```
export default {
    name: "AssignmentList",
    data() { ....
},
updated() {
    $(this.$refs.stateSelect).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

But with this method the options like "livesearch" didn't work.

```
// Select2 Livesearch
$('.livesearch').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true,
    noneSelectedText: 'Nichts ausgewählt',
});
```

I can enable the livesearch only with the "data-live-search" attribute like this:

```
<select v-model="filterState" @change="search()" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" ref="stateSelect" id="stateSelect">
```

But I want to set the options in my JS file without using the data attributes.

How can I did this?

Answer (score 0):

first thing in your `v-for` you need to bind a key, see the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) for better explanation.

second advice, if you can, don't mix jquery with vue, you don't need to do that, eg:

`$(this.$refs.stateSelect).selectpicker('refresh');`

can be:

`this.$refs.stateSelect.selectpicker('refresh'); // this can be wrong because selectpicker need a jquery object, but se the logic XD`

i don't understand very well wich is your purpose, but i think you can use the watch hook:

```
watch: {
  filterstate(){//v-model of select
    $('.livesearch').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true,
    noneSelectedText: 'Nichts ausgewählt',
});
  }
}
```

with vue for the ui you can use [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) or [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)